# How to insert Scanned data in FireBase Realtime DataBase from QR/Barcode?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code it is working fine it scans Qr/Barcode, but I want scanned data to insert in fire-base database. This app is connected with fire-base and using ML kit for barcode scanning. This app also has login signup connected with fire-base auth and scanner app. but I don't know how to push scanned data in fire-base realtime database in android studio.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    View view;
    CameraView camera_view;
    boolean isDetected= false;
    Button btn_start_again;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions options;
    FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetector detector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetector detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
                .getVisionBarcodeDetector();

        Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO})
                .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                        setupCamera();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {

                    }
                }).check();
    }
    public void logout(View view) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();//logout
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),login.class));
        finish();
    }

    private  void setupCamera()
    {
        btn_start_again= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_again);
        btn_start_again.setEnabled(isDetected);
        btn_start_again.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                isDetected = !isDetected;
            }
        });

        camera_view = (CameraView)findViewById(R.id.cameraView);
        camera_view.setLifecycleOwner(this);
        camera_view.addFrameProcessor(new FrameProcessor() {
            @Override
            public void process(@NonNull Frame frame)
            {
                processImage(getVisionImageFromFrame(frame));

            }

    });

        options = new FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions.Builder()
                .setBarcodeFormats(FirebaseVisionBarcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE)
                .build();
        detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionBarcodeDetector(options);

    }
    private void processImage(FirebaseVisionImage image){
        if(!isDetected)
        {
            detector.detectInImage(image)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<FirebaseVisionBarcode>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(List<FirebaseVisionBarcode> firebaseVisionBarcodes) {
                            processResult(firebaseVisionBarcodes);

                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

        }
    }
    private void processResult(List<FirebaseVisionBarcode> firebaseVisionBarcodes){
        if (firebaseVisionBarcodes.size()>0)
        {
            isDetected = true;
            btn_start_again.setEnabled(isDetected);
            for(FirebaseVisionBarcode item: firebaseVisionBarcodes)
            {
                int value_type = item.getValueType();
                switch (value_type)
                {
                    case FirebaseVisionBarcode.TYPE_TEXT:
                    {
                        createDialog(item.getRawValue());
                    }
                    break;
                    case FirebaseVisionBarcode.TYPE_URL:
                    {
                        //start browser intent
                        Intent intent =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(item.getRawValue()));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    break;
                    case FirebaseVisionBarcode.TYPE_CONTACT_INFO:
                    {
                        String info = new StringBuilder("Name: ")
                                .append(item.getContactInfo().getName().getFormattedName())
                                .append("\n")
                                .append("Address: ")
                                .append(item.getContactInfo().getAddresses().get(0).getAddressLines())
                                .append("\n")
                                .append("Email: ")
                                .append(item.getContactInfo().getEmails().get(0).getAddress())
                                .toString();
                        createDialog(info);

                    }
                    break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    private void createDialog(String text)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(text)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

    }

    private FirebaseVisionImage getVisionImageFromFrame(Frame frame){

        byte[] data= frame.getData();
        FirebaseVisionImageMetadata metadata = new FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.Builder()
                .setFormat(FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.IMAGE_FORMAT_NV21)
                .setHeight(frame.getSize() .getHeight())
                .setWidth(frame.getSize() .getWidth())
                //.setRotation(frame.getRotation())
                .build();
        return FirebaseVisionImage.fromByteArray(data,metadata);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any code related to the Firebase Realtime Database in your question yet. If you're new to this API, I recommend getting start through the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start) or [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/).

Comment: In this code i don't have any Realtime Database code yet. This app is working fine it scans Qr with Firebase ML kit but i want to connect it with FireBase Database like i want to store scanned data in Firebase Realtime Database  but i don't know how to do

Comment: In that case I'd recommend getting started with the codelab and documentation I linked before, as those are the best introduction to working with Firebase. There are probably some other good tutorials out there too, so you should be able to get something more working before needing our help.

Comment: I have already searched a lot. There are a lot of videos how to insert data but in my code i don't know which function should be pushed through Database Ref like i will show you i'm trying to use these functions to add values but nothing happened

Comment: reff= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("isDetected");
        reff.push().setValue(isDetected);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"data inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: i got nothing about how to insert scanned data in firebase database on youtube and google

Comment: Instead of adding the code in your comment, please edit it into your question (there's an `edit` link right under it). That way you can use the formatting features to make it more readable than is possible in comments.